# Set Theme Colors/Items

Tags: android, themes

I may have a flawed understanding of how themes work in android, so I'm just gonna say what I want to do, and someone can tell me why I'm wrong:

I'd like my application to switch between a dark and a light theme, so I've declared two themes. The theme switching works fine, the problem arises when I'd like to add an attribute that presumable doesn't exist:

```
<style name="AppThemeDark" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">#000</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">#000</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">#000</item>
    <item name="colorBackground">#000</item>
    ...
</style>
```

Which yields the result: `No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'colorBackground'.`

So I know that one of two things is at play here:

1. I somehow, somewhere need to define colorBackground, or..
2. I cannot add any new attributes and must work with the ones I am given, which seems odd to me, but hey, what do I know.

I want both of my themes to have a 'colorBackground' so that I can set the application's views' backgrounds to the corresponding theme. a light background for the light theme and a darker background for the dark theme. Ideally something like:

```
<RelativeLayout>
    ....
    android:background="?attr/colorBackground"
    ....
</RelativeLayout>
```

There may be a specific attribute that is made to do this specifically, but I do not know it.

So what am I doing wrong?

Comment: you can make style attributes when declaring then in attrs.xml and use them as your own style. this won't be an issue then.

Comment: where might I find this elusive "attrs.xml"?

Comment: you'll have to create one in values folder under res directory. For better understanding of this concept, try understanding Google IO's app. I used it to do the same.

Comment: check this out 

https://github.com/google/iosched/blob/master/android/src/main/res/values/styles.xml

Comment: form that into an answer and I can give you accepted answer